# Google-Maps API doesn't output all places?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-geocoder

I try to make a autocomplete for street-names and I use the Google-Maps for this. Simplified said, the output of

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kirch+46236+germany
```

should at least output

- Kirchplatz
- Kirchchellenerstraße

but it outputs those streets only when I request

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kirchchhellen+46236+germany
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Google geocoding service is to match your input with some address. You will get back addresses that in Google opinion are most appropriate for your search. Geocoding API doesn't return all possible addresses.

There are certain recommendation regarding formatting of your queries in order to achieve best results. You can read about this at

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=es#geocoder_queryformat

Hope it helps!